# Removing cycles in a directed graph by swapping edges orientation

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graphs

I have the following problem: let $G$ be a finite directed graph with $V$ vertices $v_i$ and $E$ (directed) edges $e_j$. I know that if an edge $e_k = (v_i, v_j)$ is in the graph, then the opposite edge $-e_k = (v_j, v_i)$ is not in the graph. I also know that the graph contains at least one cycle. My goal is to render the graph acyclic by swapping the direction of some edges **pertaining to at least one cycle**.

I figured this was simple induction reasoning, i.e. swap an edge in any given cycle thus removing it, and repeat. But I cannot find a proof that it is possible to pick an edge which would not create a new cycle when swapped, nor can I find a counter-example with a finite graph.

The lemma I'd like to prove would be: given a graph $G$ such as above, there exists edge $(v_i, v_j)$ in one of the cycles so that replacing it with its opposite $(v_j, v_i)$ decreases the number of cycles in $G$ by at least 1. However, I couldn't find anything related... Any idea?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is closely related to a standard (NP-complete) optimization problem, the minimum feedback edge set. Normally, this problem is defined as asking for the minimum set of edges $F$ to remove from a digraph $G$ to make $G-F$ acyclic. However, reversing the same set of edges $(G-F+F^R)$ also gives a DAG.

To see this, first note that each removed edge $f_i$ must be part of a cycle $C_i$ in $G-F+f_i$, or else the set of removed edges would not be minimal. But then if there were a cycle in $G-F+F^R$, you could replace each edge $f_i^R$ in this cycle by the corresponding path in $C_i-f_i$ and get a cycle in $G-F$.

The same argument works whenever $F$ is minimal, not just minimum. This might be helpful if you actually want to construct a set $F$, since it means you can do so without having to solve an NP-hard problem.

So this doesn't exactly give you a sequence of edges whose individual reversals decrease the number of cycles monotonically, but it does give you a set of edges that all participate in cycles and whose joint reversal eliminates all cycles.